# функция возвращает undefined

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

подскажите почему функция возвращает undefined

```
function f1(s) {
    if(s.match(new RegExp(/-[\d]+-/g),'-') === null){
        return s;

    } else {
        f1(s.replace(new RegExp(/-[\d]+-/g),'-'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  ...
} else {
    return f1(s.replace(new RegExp(/-[\d]+-/g),'-')); // return !!
}
```